# CTDB Samba script failing to start

Tags: ubuntu, samba, glusterfs

Here is the output from a tail -f /var/log/ctdb/log.ctdb

```
2020/01/27 18:52:52.317670 ctdbd[3330]: Running the "startup" event.
2020/01/27 18:53:22.323208 ctdbd[3330]: startup event failed
2020/01/27 18:53:22.439563 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: ===== Start of hung script debug for PID="3678", event="startup" =====
2020/01/27 18:53:22.439703 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: pstree -p -a 3678:
2020/01/27 18:53:22.439764 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: 50.samba.script,3678 /etc/ctdb/events/legacy/50.samba.script startup
2020/01/27 18:53:22.439822 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug:   `-service,3758 /sbin/service nmbd start
2020/01/27 18:53:22.439877 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug:       `-service,3762 /sbin/service nmbd start
2020/01/27 18:53:22.439953 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug:           |-sed,3764 -ne s/\.socket\s*[a-z]*\s*$/.socket/p
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440012 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug:           `-systemctl,3763 list-unit-files --full --type=socket
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440068 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: ---- ctdb scriptstatus startup: ----
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440133 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: 00.ctdb              OK         0.017 Mon Jan 27 18:52:52 2020
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440203 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: 01.reclock           OK         0.010 Mon Jan 27 18:52:52 2020
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440259 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: 05.system            OK         0.010 Mon Jan 27 18:52:52 2020
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440314 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: 10.interface         OK         0.064 Mon Jan 27 18:52:52 2020
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440382 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: 50.samba             TIMEDOUT   Mon Jan 27 18:52:52 2020
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440438 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug:   OUTPUT:
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440492 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: event daemon helper failed with error 46
2020/01/27 18:53:22.440558 ctdb-eventd[3332]: event_debug: ===== End of hung script debug for PID="3678", event="startup" =====
```

The weird thing is this was happening on my two nodes last week but when I fired them both up again the first node worked and the second node gives me this error.

I am enabling the script with

```
ctdb event script enable legacy 50.samba
```

Here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP2
        clustering = yes
        netbios name = gluster
        idmap backend = tdb2

[share]
        path = /mnt/gfs/share
        valid users = fsuser
        readonly = no
        browsable = yes
```

I am running ubuntu server 19.10 with the latest ctdb and samba. The shared file system is glusterfs and that portion is working as it should and passes the ping_pong test.

I also am seeing this message using journalctl -b

```
Dec 03 16:28:18 gfs1 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:4: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file acc
Dec 03 16:28:18 gfs1 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/smbd.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/samba/smbd.pid → /run/samba/smbd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Dec 03 16:28:18 gfs1 systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/samba/nmbd.pid → /run/samba/nmbd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Dec 03 16:28:18 gfs1 systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around to this. I disable the ctdb samba legacy script and use the normal systemctl startup scripts.

```
sudo systemctl edit ctdb
```

Add the following and save and exit

```
[Unit]
Require=mnt-gfs.mount
After=mnt-gfs.mount
```

To find out your .mount you can run this command and switch out the mount patch with your glusterfs or other distributed files systems mount point.

```
sudo systemctl list-units | grep '/mnt/gfs' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Then its just a mater of editing the smbd and nmbd service files.

```
sudo systemctl edit smbd.service
sudo systemctl edit nmbd.service
```

Then add this to both of the above files, save and exit each one

```
[Unit]
After=ctdb.service
```

Make sure ctdb is up and running and run this command (start it with systemctl start ctdb if its not running)

```
sudo ctdb event script enable legacy 50.samba
```

Reboot your node and it should mount your distributed file system share, start ctdb and then start smbd and nmbd.

Answer (score 0):

The pstree output suggests that "service nmbd start" is hanging when it tries to do systemd things.

What happens if you try "service nmbd start" in a terminal?  How about "systemctl start nmbd"?

Comment: When I run sudo systemctl start nmbd while ctdb is running it starts up fine.

If I disable the ctdb samba script and restart ctdb and then start nmbd and smbd everything seems to work as it should.